# $Ax = b$ has an infinite number of solutions if $\dim(null(A)) \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking through my old linear algebra notes, and I have written that

> For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $Ax = b$ has an infinite number of solutions if $\dim(\operatorname{null}(A)) \neq 0$.

This seems to not be sufficient because if $b$ is not in the column space of $A$, then $Ax = b$ has no solution. So for $Ax = b$ to have an infinite number of solutions, is it that we must have $\dim(\operatorname{null}(A)) \neq 0$ AND $b$ is in the column space of $A$?

Comment: Yes. You need $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be in the column space of $A$ to ensure that $Ax=b$ is consistent in the first place. If $x_0$ is a known solution to the augmented system $[A|b]$, then noting $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^m:Ax=b\}=x_0+ \text{Null}(A)$$ gives you your infinitely many solutions.

Comment: What does $+ Null(A)$ represent here on the RHS? Is it adding the linear combination of the vectors that span the null space of $A$?

Comment: $$x_0+\text{Null}(A)=\{x_0+x:x\in \text{Null}(A)\}$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think I may be misunderstanding something, but when you write $x \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$, does this read that "$x$ is a vector from the nullspace of $A$." The nullspace of $A$ is the set of non-zero vectors $u$ such that $Au = 0$. So that does this mean $x$ is just one of these vectors?

Comment: $0$ is in the nullspace also,.  $x$ can be any of those vectors.  Note by linearity,  $A(x_0+x)=Ax_0+Ax=Ax_0+0=Ax_0=b$